# Redmine Incoming emails, Is it possible to use Encrypted password with the Rake task

Tags: encryption, rake, redmine, rake-task, rakefile

I've configured redmine to accept incoming emails to create tickets. The rake task that I am running as a cron has the password for the receiving email entered as plain text . Instead can I use an encrypted password ? or is there any other method to securely give password ?

```
eg:
rake --trace redmine:email:receive_pop3 RAILS_ENV="production" host=my.mail.com port=110 username=fin@mydomain.com
password={encrypted-password} project=myproject allow_override=tracker,status,description,priority,assignee,category
```

Answer (score 0):

Each of the arguments to the rake task can also be given as environment variables with the same name. That way, they don't turn up in the process list. The password itself can then be sourced from an external (secured) file or gathered from a other sources.

```
password=SuP3rS3cu4e rake --trace redmine:email:receive_pop3 ...
```

In any case, rake needs access to the raw unencrypted password since it needs it to connect to the POP3 server.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [this gem](http://rocketjob.github.io/symmetric-encryption/) to support symmetric encryption for ruby and rail project's data.